# Encode & Decode string in WPF C#

Tags: c#, decode, encode

I am trying to encode & decode strings that are saved to an .ini settings file for a WPF app.

**encoding & decoding class**

```
class EncryptDecrypt
{

    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }

    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }

}
```

The encoding seems to be saved to the .ini file correctly, but decoding the entry from the .ini file seems to output incorrect string as per below;

**encoding from password field works fine (on save_click)**

```
inif.Write("APISettings", "HashKey", EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(hash_key.Password.ToString()));
```

but, reload app then navigating to same field/form the decode is not outputting entry correctly (as it is used to check http status of page)..

```
hash_key.Password = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Decode(inif.Read("APISettings", "HashKey"));
```

I can see that is outputting the string as weird wingdings characters.

**UPDATE**

Resolved by instead of saving to .ini file I saved to xml document, see below;

```
        private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Settings Data
        string appfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string ApplicationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appfolder, "MyApp/Application");
        if (!Directory.Exists(ApplicationPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(ApplicationPath);

        //Encryption

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ApplicationPath + @"\credentials.xml"))
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            //(1) the xml declaration is recommended, but not mandatory
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

            //(2) string.Empty makes cleaner code
            XmlElement elementNode = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Credentials", string.Empty);
            doc.AppendChild(elementNode);

            //Base URL
            XmlElement elementNodeBaseUrl = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "BaseUrl", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeBaseUrl);
            elementNodeBaseUrl.InnerText = base_url.Text.ToString();

            XmlElement elementNodeAdminPath = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "AdminPath", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeAdminPath);
            elementNodeAdminPath.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(admin_path.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeAdminName = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "AdminName", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeAdminName);
            elementNodeAdminName.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(admin_name.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeAdminPassword = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "AdminPassword", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeAdminPassword);
            elementNodeAdminPassword.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(admin_password.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeHashKey = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "HashKey", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeHashKey);
            elementNodeHashKey.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(hash_key.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeUpdated = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Updated", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeUpdated);
            elementNodeUpdated.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            doc.Save(ApplicationPath + @"\credentials.xml");

        }else{

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            //(1) the xml declaration is recommended, but not mandatory
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

            //(2) string.Empty makes cleaner code
            XmlElement elementNode = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Credentials", string.Empty);
            doc.AppendChild(elementNode);

            //Base URL
            XmlElement elementNodeBaseUrl = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "BaseUrl", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeBaseUrl);
            elementNodeBaseUrl.InnerText = base_url.Text.ToString();

            XmlElement elementNodeAdminPath = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "AdminPath", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeAdminPath);
            elementNodeAdminPath.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(admin_path.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeAdminName = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "AdminName", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeAdminName);
            elementNodeAdminName.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(admin_name.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeAdminPassword = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "AdminPassword", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeAdminPassword);
            elementNodeAdminPassword.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(admin_password.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeHashKey = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "HashKey", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeHashKey);
            elementNodeHashKey.InnerText = EncryptDecrypt.Base64Encode(hash_key.Password.ToString());

            XmlElement elementNodeUpdated = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Updated", string.Empty);
            elementNode.AppendChild(elementNodeUpdated);
            elementNodeUpdated.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            doc.Save(ApplicationPath + @"\credentials.xml");
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);


        SaveButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        onclick_progress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        showProgress();

    }
```

Comment: Example taken from http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/45809-EnCode-and-Decode-Base64-String.aspx

Comment: Does the saved value decode successfully at https://www.base64decode.org ?

Comment: no just loads empty value using utf-8

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. I think you are reading the int entry using some file stream, set the encoding of file stream to UTF8. Also use some encryption algorithm to encypt the data not just base 64 encoding